# How can I drop rows from a data frame where the row contains a duplicate value in the row itself?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large data frame and I would like to efficiently drop any row if the row does not have all unique elements within the row itself. They can be duplicated in any of the columns more than once.

```
    0   1   2   4   3
0   13  3   2   0   3
1   13  72  2   13  1
2   13  3   2   8   5
```

Here I would like to drop rows 0 and 1 because row 0 has `3` in two places and row 2 has `13` in two places.

Answer (score 1):

Use series `is_unique`

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.is_unique, axis=1)]
#     0  1  2  4  3
# 2  13  3  2  8  5
```

Comment: This gets the job done, I am wondering if there is a more efficient solution since this takes ~12 seconds on my machine to go through 1 million rows